# How to resolve the "ERROR No Major.Minor.Patch elements found" during ksonnet init step in AWS EKS setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, kubeflow, ksonnet

I'm following the official AWS EKS [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deep-learning-containers/latest/devguide/deep-learning-containers-eks-tutorials-distributed-gpu-training.html#deep-learning-containers-eks-tutorials-distributed-gpu-training-tf) on setting up a distributed GPU cluster for Tensorflow model training and am hitting a bit of a snag.

After creating a new cluster using `eksctl` and verifying that the corresponding `~/.kube/config` file exists on my gateway node, the tutorial instructs that I [download `ksonnet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deep-learning-containers/latest/devguide/deep-learning-containers-eks-setup.html#deep-learning-containers-eks-setup-gateway-node) on the gateway node and use it to initialize a new application:

```
$ ks init <app-name>
```

When I try running this, however, I receive the following error:

```
INFO Using context "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:131397771409:cluster/<cluster name>" from kubeconfig file "/home/ubuntu/.kube/config"
INFO Creating environment "default" with namespace "default", pointing to "version:v1.18.9" cluster at address <cluster address>
ERROR No Major.Minor.Patch elements found
```

I've done some searching around on Github/SO, but have not been able to find a resolution to this issue. I suspect the true answer is to move away from using `ksonnet`, as it is no longer being maintained (and hasn't been for the last 2 years it appears), but for the time being I'd just like to be able to complete the tutorial :)

Any insight is appreciated!

Contents of my `~/.kube/config`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <certificate>
    server: <server>
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:131397771409:cluster/<name>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:131397771409:cluster/<name>
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:131397771409:cluster/<name>
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:131397771409:cluster/<name>
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:131397771409:cluster/<name>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:131397771409:cluster/<name>
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-west-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - <name>
      command: aws
```

Answer (score 1):

On the init, you can override the api spec version (that worked for me on that particular step although I got into other issues later on):

```
ks init ${APP_NAME} --api-spec=version:v1.7.0
```

[Reference](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/521#issuecomment-379501901)

In the end, I made it work with `ks init ${APP_NAME}` (without `--api-spec`) in GCP using ksonnet v0.13.1 on old kubeflow (v0.2.0-rc.1) and GKE cluster (1.14.10) versions.
BTW, I was in "Kubeflow: End to End" qwiklab from this [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/gcp-production-ml-systems).